# Error: Option 'ajax' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element woocommerce

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-select2

any body help me wasted too much time on this error but no luck

> Error: Option 'ajax' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a
>    element.

this error show in my developer console after updating woocommerce to 3.0.3 this error broken some of functionalities like could not add the upsell and cross up text boxed are noting.

When I chnaged my theme then this go away and I can't change my theme.

Please help.

Comment: see https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/679

Comment: from the read i think you need a newer version of select 2

Comment: I have no idea where to change this and update this is in my theme and woocommerce conflicting.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Fresh installs work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error in my wordpress website, and I fixed that so.

1st I want to describe where this error comes from.
From WC Beta 2, they've migrated to Select2 V4. Select2 V4 is mostly compatible with Select2 V3 with a few exceptions, the main one being how AJAX search inputs work. WooCommerce has two instances of these which are affected and need some HTML markup changes to function.
For Example

```
<input type="hidden" id="grant_access_id" name="grant_access_id" data-multiple="true" class="wc-product-search" style="width: 400px;" data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search for a downloadable product&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" data-action="woocommerce_json_search_downloadable_products_and_variations" />
```

was changed with

```
<select id="grant_access_id" class="wc-product-search" name="grant_access_id[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 400px;" data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search for a downloadable product&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" data-action="woocommerce_json_search_downloadable_products_and_variations"></select>
```

In wordpress I saw that select2 takes control, and I tried to disable select2 load in my functions.php. You can see my script below

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_views_select2' );

function remove_views_select2($hook) {
    if ( ( $hook == 'post.php' || $hook == 'post-new.php' ) ) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'select2' );
        // wp_register_script( 'views-select2-script' , 'http://your-site.com/wp-content/plugins/meta-box/js/select2/select2.min.js', array('jquery'), 3.2);
    }
}
```

So that works excellent in my case. Good luck !  😉

Comment: in my case i changed  to `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.js` from `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.3/js/select2.js` i dont work on CMS but custom web app